# remove duplicates from dropdownlist in PHP

Tags: php

I have a text file like this:

```
unfinished  unfinished  17876   open        peters      Current/17876 - 
unfinished  unfinished  17830   new         peters      Current/17830 - 
unfinished  unfinished  17810   new         jongr       Current/17810 -
```

I want to list all items from the 5th column. However if there is a duplicate I don't want it to be listed twice. The code I have so far is:

```
<select>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',"1");

$lines = file('C://projectlist/project-list.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line){
    $parts = explode('  ', $line);

    echo "<option>{$parts[4]}</option>";
}



?>
</select>
```

However this just lists all names in the drop down box.

Comment: Maybe you should write the 5th column into a separate array first and then use that array to generate the dropdown list. You can use `array_key_exists()` for that array to check if the name exists in it before adding the name to it.

Comment: Posted a complete answer Amy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `array_unique();`
An example:

```
$my_array = array_unique($my_array);
```

Or another solution using the specifics from your post:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',"1");

    $select = '<select>';

    $lines = file('project-list.txt');
    $fifth_column = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line){
        $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($parts as $partVal){
            if ((in_array($partVal, $fifth_column) == FALSE) && $count == 4){
                $fifth_column[] = $partVal;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }

    foreach($fifth_column as $value){
        $select .= "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
    }

    $select .= '</select>';

    echo $select;
?>
```

Comment: 1. *Just try* how? 2. What should OP do with it, why should he use it?

Comment: @Rizier123 will add example now

Comment: Thank you @Rizier123 and @1" an example would be helpful

Comment: Thank you @1" I am a little confused, only started using PHP this week. Thanks for your help x

Comment: @Amy Not to worry I'll help all I can. Headed to work. Will post in 15

Comment: Brilliant, works a treat! I have marked it as the answer. Thanks again :-) @1"

Comment: I was just wondering @1" how would I use this when trying to see which items a user as selected. I would use isser $_POST but the multiselect box doesn't have a name? TIA

Comment: sorry I mean $_GET @1"

Comment: @Amy Do you use ajax? Trying to store in Database?

Comment: No I have never used AJAX, basically on a button click I wanted it to search the textdocument for the name/s the user had selected in the multi select box and then display the results on the page. @1"

Comment: Definitely look into databases. There are builtin command to do the exact think you're describing. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice little function for that. You can read about it [here](http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2015/05/removing-duplicate-rows-from-2.html).

Here's an example: http://3v4l.org/uGgU4

```
function doopScooper($dataArray, $uniqueKeys){

    // store the the previously checked sub-arrays here
    $checked = array();

    //loop through the array
    foreach($dataArray as $k=>$row){

        // this will become the sub array that needs to be checked
        $checkArray = array();

        //create the sub array for comparison
        foreach($uniqueKeys as $key)
            $checkArray[$key] = isset($row[$key]) ? $row[$key] : NULL;

        // convert sub array to string for easy comparison
        $checkArray = json_encode($checkArray);

        // check for duplicates, if found delete, else add to the checking array
        if(in_array($checkArray, $checked)) unset($dataArray[$k]);
        else $checked[] = $checkArray;

    }
    return $dataArray;
}

$lines = "unfinished  unfinished  17876   open        peters      Current/17876 - 
unfinished  unfinished  17830   new         peters      Current/17830 - 
unfinished  unfinished  17810   new         jongr       Current/17810 -";

$lines = explode("\n",$lines);
$parts=[];
foreach ($lines as $line) $parts[] = explode('  ', $line);

//remove duplicates from the 7th column
$lines = doopScooper($parts, array(7));

foreach ($lines as $line) echo "<option>{$parts[4]}</option>";
```